# Best way to iterate hierarchical JSON/JS data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm hitting some performance issues with various implementations of this...

Essentially, I have a dataset of around 1500 objects in the below form: -

```
  {
    "Id": "411fc047-9d58-4faf-8da2-dfaf1fc3f3a3",
    "ParentId": null,
    "Name": "Main Location",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Id": "3cb93d59-613c-4797-8858-bc3f31f6baa0",
        "ParentId": "411fc047-9d58-4faf-8da2-dfaf1fc3f3a3",
        "Name": "Site A",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Id": "a1fec942-b425-4307-905d-9e2a6f8730b3",
            "ParentId": "3cb93d59-613c-4797-8858-bc3f31f6baa0",
            "Name": "Location A1",
            "Children": [
              {
                "Id": "5538e976-db1c-49c2-8cab-70aafc1e4e70",
                "ParentId": "a1fec942-b425-4307-905d-9e2a6f8730b3",
                "Name": "Location A1 a",
                "Children": []
              },
              {
                "Id": "6f5a536f-4b4f-4a10-b7ba-657d772d0588",
                "ParentId": "a1fec942-b425-4307-905d-9e2a6f8730b3",
                "Name": "Location A1 b",
                "Children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "319db987-994d-45d5-9023-8f21b8a589cb",
        "ParentId": "411fc047-9d58-4faf-8da2-dfaf1fc3f3a3",
        "Name": "Site B",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Id": "f0c1f222-4118-4c07-b7be-30ff70fada03",
            "ParentId": "319db987-994d-45d5-9023-8f21b8a589cb",
            "Name": "Location B1",
            "Children": [
              {
                "Id": "fe33043d-4cf2-498e-aa80-04848e109acb",
                "ParentId": "f0c1f222-4118-4c07-b7be-30ff70fada03",
                "Name": "Location B1 b",
                "Children": []
              },
              {
                "Id": "d92ae7d5-bc44-4e94-be75-0cda5a254664",
                "ParentId": "f0c1f222-4118-4c07-b7be-30ff70fada03",
                "Name": "Location B1 b",
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "Id": "0a89ee4a-3b18-4772-baa3-fc0682d7053f",
                    "ParentId": "d92ae7d5-bc44-4e94-be75-0cda5a254664",
                    "Name": "Location B1 b Special Site...",
                    "Children": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It has an unknown depth, as in the children can continue to exist on each object...

Firstly, I would love to know what would be the fastest way to search this to find one of the objects given an Id (GUID). I have tried all sorts, I've experimented with flattening it out and using ES6 .find() (instead of filter for singular results...), I've written a custom iterator that essentially starts at the top and works it's way through the children until a match is found... These solutions work, I'm just wondering if there's a trick I'm missing..?

- One area this slows down is if I want to then climb the tree from the found object, so if I use the .find() approach, and I want to know all of it's parents, I then need to also find() each parent based on the ParentId...

Secondly, now this perhaps is a bit of a unique use case, but essentially, I populate a customised React Treeview in JS with this data, and in the treeview, each item has a checkbox... Once the user checks the box, I add the object Id attribute to a 'selected' array to track what has been selected and what hasn't...

Where this gets complicated, is I don't want to then select all of the parent items above it, but instead need to know their ids so I can store them in a 'partially selected' array to illustrate on the Treeview that they haven't been selected, but a child of it somewhere has... (I conditionally change the styling of the checkbox depending if it's a Selected or 'Partially Selected' checkbox...

This is the key area where the slowdown occurs, because the User might check only 3 or 4 checkboxes mid way down the tree, which will also check all of their children, and this these 'partially selected' ids need to be found for each 'fully' checked item in the tree...

Make sense? :-S

I'm wondering basically, is there some super duper fast way that people usually use when working with things like this or is the nature of it slow and that's that because I simply need to check each route individually..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a hash map and have a fast access to the wanted objects.

```js
const
    buildHashMap = (r, o) => {
        r[o.Id] = o;
        return o.Children
            ? o.Children.reduce(buildHashMap, r)
            : r;
    },
    data = [{ Id: "411fc047-9d58-4faf-8da2-dfaf1fc3f3a3", ParentId: null, Name: "Main Location", Children: [{ Id: "3cb93d59-613c-4797-8858-bc3f31f6baa0", ParentId: "411fc047-9d58-4faf-8da2-dfaf1fc3f3a3", Name: "Site A", Children: [{ Id: "a1fec942-b425-4307-905d-9e2a6f8730b3", ParentId: "3cb93d59-613c-4797-8858-bc3f31f6baa0", Name: "Location A1", Children: [{ Id: "5538e976-db1c-49c2-8cab-70aafc1e4e70", ParentId: "a1fec942-b425-4307-905d-9e2a6f8730b3", Name: "Location A1 a", Children: [] }, { Id: "6f5a536f-4b4f-4a10-b7ba-657d772d0588", ParentId: "a1fec942-b425-4307-905d-9e2a6f8730b3", Name: "Location A1 b", Children: [] }] }] }, { Id: "319db987-994d-45d5-9023-8f21b8a589cb", ParentId: "411fc047-9d58-4faf-8da2-dfaf1fc3f3a3", Name: "Site B", Children: [{ Id: "f0c1f222-4118-4c07-b7be-30ff70fada03", ParentId: "319db987-994d-45d5-9023-8f21b8a589cb", Name: "Location B1", Children: [{ Id: "fe33043d-4cf2-498e-aa80-04848e109acb", ParentId: "f0c1f222-4118-4c07-b7be-30ff70fada03", Name: "Location B1 b", Children: [] }, { Id: "d92ae7d5-bc44-4e94-be75-0cda5a254664", ParentId: "f0c1f222-4118-4c07-b7be-30ff70fada03", Name: "Location B1 b", Children: [{ Id: "0a89ee4a-3b18-4772-baa3-fc0682d7053f", ParentId: "d92ae7d5-bc44-4e94-be75-0cda5a254664", Name: "Location B1 b Special Site...", Children: [] }] }] }] }] }],
    hashmap = data.reduce(buildHashMap, {});

console.log(hashmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Had you tried a custom recursive function?

```
function findId(data, id) {
  const { Id, Children } = data;

  if(id === Id) return data;
  if(! Children || Children.length === 0) return null;

  for(let i = 0; i < Children.length; ++i) {
    const ret = findId(Children[i], id);

    if(ret) return ret;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Hope this helps.